# Closing BufferedReader and InputStreamReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

This piece of code is creating memory leak issues cause of [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) which I think might be happening cause of some exceptions. How should I change it?

```
try{
    URL url = new URL(sMyUrl);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        jsonString += str;
    }
    in.close();
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

Comment: May be move close() logic to finally block? Are you sure no exceptions happening while reading  (or) closing connection?

Comment: Have tried writing `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch-clause to see if exceptions where thrown?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would be safer to close your stream using a `try..finally` block. You might also use a `StringBuilder` as it is designed for concatenating strings. You should also avoid catching `Exception` and doing nothing with it. Also, your code is concatenating lines without any line-breaks. This may well not be what you want, in which case `append("\n")` when you read each line in.

Here's a version with those modifications:

```
StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
try {
    URL url = new URL(sMyUrl);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    try {
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            json.append(str).append("\n");
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read JSON from stream", e);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to close InputStreamReader ? Or its closed as Buffer reader will create a new object?

Comment: No need to explicitly close the `InputStreamReader` as it will be closed automatically when you close the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: @aetheria, thank you. Anyhow I need a good Java streams tutorial.

Comment: @aetheria I have seen in some tutorials, the resource is being checked for null ness before closing. But when I try that one it asked me to enclosed them in another try catch block. why is that? and is it essential to check for null ness before closing a resource

Comment: Kasun, I suggest you post a separate question with an example.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as it doesn't even compile (at least in java7). Variable `BufferedReader in` is declared in scope of `try` block and is not visible in scope of `finally` block. The variable may not even get assigned in case `MalformedURLException` is thrown from URL class constructor.

Comment: No, this is a misreading. There are two `try` blocks. The variable `in` is not defined inside the `try` block that closes it.

Comment: @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ You're right. Something must be wrong with me then. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 12):

The code isn't pretty but won't be creating a memory leak. I suggest you use a memory profiler to determine where your memory is being used.  Otherwise you are just guessing even if you have ten + years experience performance tuning in Java ;)

A better alternative is to use Java 7

```
URL url = new URL(sMyUrl);
try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
  while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
     jsonString.append(str).append("\n");
  }
}
```

If you have Java 6 or older you can use.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
try {
  while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
     jsonString.append(str).append("\n");
  }
} finally {
  in.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do I need to close InputStreamReader ?

Comment: @SoneshDabhi When you close the BufferedReader it closes InputStreamreader which closes the InputStream you got from openStream() etc.